# Button to delete sql row: BadMethodCallException on Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, controller

I am new on Laravel.

I create on productedit.blade.php delete button:

```
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['DashboardController@destroy', $product->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right']) !!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

What I am doing bad with {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}} ?

DashboardController@destroy:

```
public function destroy(Request $id)
{
   $product = Product::find($id);
   $product->delete();
   return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Product Deleted');
}
```

Because I have an error:

BadMethodCallException
Method delete does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public function destroy(Request $id)
{
   $product = Product::find($id);
   $product->delete();
   return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Product Deleted');
}
```

To

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   $product = Product::find($id);
   $product->delete();
   return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Product Deleted');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jeune Guerrier,

Yes the problem was on (Request $id). Then I just deleted Request, delete command now working.

Alexey Mezenin, thank you to for answer.